# React typescript error after second submiting form

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

When i submit form for first time, everything works, but when i refresh the page i am getting an error after submit

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client'
import './Register.css'

const Register = () => {
    const registerForm = document.querySelector('.register-form') as HTMLFormElement
    const prisma = new PrismaClient()

    interface User{
        firstname: string
        email: string
        password: string
    }

    function registerNewUser(userData: User) {
        // const createUser = await prisma.user.create({
        //     data: {
        //         name: userData.firstname,
        //         email: userData.email,
        //         password: userData.password
        //     }
        // })
        console.log(userData)
    }

    return <div className="register-card" id='form'>
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form className="register-form">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="firstname"/>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"/>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
        <button onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            const firstname: string = registerForm.firstname.value
            const email: string = registerForm.email.value
            const password: string = registerForm.password.value

            const newUser: User = {
                firstname: firstname,
                email: email,
                password: password
            }

            registerNewUser(newUser)
        }}>Register</button>
    </form>
    <Link to="/"><p>I have an account</p></Link>
</div>;
}
 
export default Register;
```

I tried to set this function async, but it didn't work, i expect to function registerNewUser works and console.log 'userData'

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstname')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstname')
    at onClick (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:300:42)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15644:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15688:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15745:35)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15759:29)

Comment: at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19902:7)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19928:11)
    at processDispatchQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19939:9)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19948:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:20108:16

Answer (score 0):

Okay i already found the problem, i just had to move form declaration into onClick function

Comment: This is not a solution. This response is better moved into a comment or updating the original question to include this context